# PORT names ans CONST in an array

Tags: pic, port

uC: PIC18F46K20

I want to scan, in a loop, different ports and test different pins on each port.

I have different target boards so I want to be able to quickly configure each board in CONST arrays. So I created arrays like these:

```
const char my_ports[4] = {PORTB, PORTB, PORTD, PORTA}; // <- this is the PROBLEM causing line
const char my_pins[4] = {3, 7, 1, 4};
```

in order to be able to scan those ports in a loop:

```
// NEW version of the func.
void pin_update(void)
{
  for (k=0; k<=3; k++)
  {
    if (my_ports[k] & my_pins[k])
    {
     // and actions here ........
    }
  }
}
```

---

But compiler comes up with an error :

```
        "my_ports[] ... constant expression required"
```

I used the approach of passing the port name (eg. PORTB) in previous version of the code when each pin was tested individually, eg. :

```
    pin_update(PORTB, 3);   
            // ...
    pin_update(PORTD, 1);   

// OLD version of the func:
void pin_update(char prt, char pn)
{
    if (prt & pn)
    {
     // and actions here ........
    }
}
```

and all was OK and code worked properly. But as you see PORTB is hard coded in a parameter list. And now I want to run the above 'pin updates' in a loop.

So problem came out when I wanted to list port names in CONST array.
I tried various things with casting to ports' addresses etc - nothing worked. Compiler still did not like it.

Comment: `my_pins` looks suspicious. Are you sure you don't mean `1 << 3` etc.?

Comment: no, 'my_pins[]' is an array of pin numbers that relate to the 'my_ports[] of port names (addresses).
So the loop 'for (k=0; k<=3; k++)'
first tests tests if PORTB.3, then PORTB.7 etc
And it works fine in real code on real target.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is correct. `PORTx` *aren't* constant; they result in the value stored in hardware. You need to store a *pointer* to the port and then dereference it when appropriate.

```
const *char my_ports[4] = {&PORTB, &PORTB, &PORTD, &PORTA};
const char my_pins[4] = {3, 7, 1, 4};

 ...

void pin_update(void)
{
  for (k=0; k<=3; k++)
  {
    if (*(my_ports[k]) & my_pins[k])
    {
     // and actions here ........
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes it is better but unfortunately compiler does not like that either: Warning ... illegal conversion between pointer types:
pointer to volatile unsigned char -> pointer to const unsigned char

So I tried this:
const char *my_ports[4] = {&PORTB, &PORTB, &PORTD, &PORTA};
and compiler does not complain but code build is incorrect. In debugger I looked at the array and it looked like this:
my_ports
[0] 0x81
[1] 0x0F
[2] 0x81
[3] 0x0F
NOTE: XC8 compiler's header file for pic18f46k20 micro has this:
// Register: PORTB
extern volatile unsigned char PORTB @ 0xF81;
I will come back to this soon....

Comment: i.e. port address is INT long, so I changed it to :
const unsigned int *my_ports[4] = {&PORTB, &PORTB, &PORTD, &PORTA};
Then in debugger I saw this:
my_ports                                     
[0]  0x0F81
[1]  0x0F81
Compiler still issues similar warning about illegal conversion, but at least pointers array 
is OK. 
I will have to debug the code though to see if pin values are read properly, and then somehow fix the compiler complaining too. I will come back with results...

Answer (score 1):

**Thank you Ignacio for the right direction.**

Here is the final solution that actually works fine: no compiler complains and the results during the program run are also correct, i.e. code properly checks individual bits of each port.

```
volatile unsigned char* const my_ports[4] = {&PORTB, &PORTB, &PORTD, &PORTA};
const char my_pins[4] = {3, 7, 1, 4};
```

and the function that uses the above pin_update() is in Ignacio's unchanged form:

```
    void pin_update(void)
    {
        for (k=0; k<=3; k++)
        {
            if (*(my_ports[k]) & my_pins[k])
            {
             // and actions here ........
            }
        }
    }
```

So now my_ports[] is an array of const pointers to a volatile unsigned chars, and it is ok because the addresses that this array holds are for actual hardware port addresses of 'volatile unsigned char' types defined in PIC18F46K20 header file as follows:

```
extern volatile unsigned char PORTB @ 0xF81; 
extern volatile unsigned char PORTC @ 0xF82; // etc...
```